# Pass input to a script: stdin vs file path in argv

Tags: bash, shell, coding-style

I write many simple scripts for testing or processing CSV files. Most of scripts have same logic: read one file and write the output to a console or another file. For such case I usually use the simplest for implementation approach: read from `stdin`, write to `stdout`, so invocation is like:

```
script < input.csv > output.csv
```

Can you give some points why I shall prefer this style:

```
script input.csv > output.csv
```

Or even:

```
script input.csv output.csv
```

Comment: Personally, I think a good filter-ish program should do both - if a file name is not given, read `stdin` and if an output file name is not given, write to `stdout`. Also, if you want to read several files, `script file1 file2 file3 ...` is slightly better than `cat file1 file2 file3 | script`, maybe... But this isn't really a right/wrong good/bad type of issue, it's more personal preference with a bit of "how is it designed to be used" thrown in...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how I deal with the same task now, similar to what @gniourf_gniourf's answer does (except my scripts are in Haskell).

When the program is invoked with arguments, like `CMD INPUT1 [INPUT2 [...]]`, treat them as input files and ignore standard input, except for special case when one or more args are `-`.

When no args are given, read standard input. So `CMD` call without args is equivalent to `CMD -`.

Answer (score 0):

Here's how you can have a script that handles both (not guaranteed to be 100% safe, maybe someone can give better options or pinpoint serious issues in a comment):

```
#!/bin/bash

if [[ -n $1 ]]; then
    exec "$0" < "$1" || exit $?
fi

# your program starts here, reading stdin, e.g.,
while read; do
   echo "$REPLY"
done
```